# puppet define array loop

Tags: loops, manifest, puppet

I am playing with `define` array but not understand why its not working in following example. I am trying to create following directions

```
/tmp/foo.0
/tmp/foo.1
/tmp/foo.2
```

My `init.pp`

```
class loop {

define loop ( $x ) {

exec {"$name":
        command => "/bin/mkdir /tmp/$name.$x",
        creates => "/tmp/$name.$x",
        }
}
loop{ "foo": x => ["0", "1", "2"] }

}
```

Its creating directory like `/tmp/tomcat7.012`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure this is a good idea to name the define with same name than class.

It would work if you invert the $name and $x

```
class loop {

  define loop::loop ( $x ) {

    exec {"$x":
      command => "/bin/mkdir /tmp/$x.$name",
      creates => "/tmp/$x.$name",
    }
  }
  loop::loop{ ["0", "1", "2"]: x => "foo" }
}
```

Hope this helps